# Linear algebra problem: How to read this line notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I've come across something I haven't seen before. I was wondering how one reads this notation of a line:
$$m:\begin{bmatrix}15\\12\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}15\\12\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}6\\-\frac{91}{12}\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: That actually doesn't make sense, as typed/printed. One cannot multiply two vectors.

Comment: @TedShifrin It could be a dot product of two vectors but where the mutliplication dot was (for some strange reason) omitted. It seems to me like the only reasonable explanation. Could you maybe add more context *AKJZ*, like where this equation occured?

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. The case of the missing dot.

Comment: @mrtaurho Online homework. We're supposed to find intersection between this line and another line. The other line is written in the "more conventional form" that we know of in Linear Algebra: L: (x,y) = (v1, v2) + lambda(u1, u2)

Comment: @AKJZ Then it should be interpreted as *Ted Shifrin* suggests within his answer below, i.e. as dot product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make sense of this is to write
$$\begin{bmatrix} 15 & 12 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 15 & 12 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 6\\-\frac{91}{12} \end{bmatrix}.$$
This can be written $15x + 12y = 15(6) + 12 (-\frac{91}{12})$.